# Тире или двоеточие в вопросительном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Что предпочтительнее: тире или двоеточие? Пример: «Климакс — что это такое и в чём он проявляется?» Это не заголовок, формулировку просят не менять.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше написать так: ***Климакс — что это такое и в чём он проявляется?***

**Пояснение**

1. Выбор тире или двоеточия рассматривается в двух темах: [§ 72. Вариативные знаки препинания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=185#pp185)  и [Знаки препинания при именительном темы](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110)
2. В общем  случае вариант **с именительным темы** используется как **в заголовках**, так и **в самом тексте**.
3. Двоеточие — это как бы **остановка речи** (интонационное предупреждение, увеличенная пауза), оно и по смыслу, и по интонации больше подходит **для заголовка.** Тире более уместно **в тексте**, так как там автор сразу переходит  **к  раскрытию** заданной в предложении темы.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае ставится двоеточие, поскольку подразумевается, что вторая часть поясняет первую.
Тире же используется в случае следствия.

Comment: Не все так однозначно. Почитайте http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=185#pp185

Comment: Спасибо за источник. Однако в описанном случае выше я гораздо чаще видел использование двоеточия, чем тире.

Comment: Тогда желательно  привести эти примеры для убедительности или найти в учебниках рекомендации по выбору подобных  вариантов.

Comment: Спасибо, учту Ваши рекомендации при ответах.